# Unwanted factors appearing in Boxplot

Tags: r

Thanks once again for the helpful comments. I  have attempted to implement your suggestions (drop = T and droplevels) but still have the original problem. Here is the problem so far:
When I attempt to make a boxplot of 'HAFREN1' , the plot appears but still with all the factors from 'NPS' - how might I stop these from appearing as part of the plot? Thanks again.

```
    NPS <- read.csv(choose.files(), header = T)

    attach(NPS)

    boxplot(K.CM.DAY~site.id, las = 3,
    par(mar = c(13,4,2,2)))

    NPSsplit1 <- split(NPS, NPS$site.id, drop=T)

    HAFREN1 <- rbind(NPSsplit1$`HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS`, NPSsplit1$`HAF MATURE 
    TREES`, NPSsplit1$`HAF YNG TREES`)

   detach(NPS)
   attach(HAFREN1)
   droplevels(HAFREN1, exclude = c("NEWBO' GRAZED", "NEWBO' UNGRAZED", 
              "NEWBO' OLD DUNES", "S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS",
              "S.L NAT GRZD GRASS", "S.L  pheasant woods", "S.L GRZD IMPRVD 
       GRASS","S.L GRAZED TREES", "S.F TREES", "S.F ARABLE", "S.F FLORISTIC 
      GRASS","S.F GRAZED GRASS" ))

    boxplot(K.CM.DAY~site.id, data = HAFREN1)
```

Here is the full data for 'NPS'

```
                    site.id     K.CM.SEC    K.CM.DAY
1             NEWBO' GRAZED 1.916489e-03 165.5846836
2             NEWBO' GRAZED 5.685340e-04  49.1213616
3             NEWBO' GRAZED 5.185110e-04  44.7993185
4             NEWBO' GRAZED 1.434850e-04  12.3970979
5           NEWBO' UNGRAZED 7.947200e-04  68.6638281
6           NEWBO' UNGRAZED 1.497260e-04  12.9363503
7           NEWBO' UNGRAZED 4.506080e-04  38.9325075
8          NEWBO' OLD DUNES 9.605890e-05   8.2994922
9          NEWBO' OLD DUNES 3.004300e-04  25.9571866
10         NEWBO' OLD DUNES 3.163820e-04  27.3353784
11         NEWBO' OLD DUNES 2.599810e-04  22.4623165
12         PUM GRAZED GRASS 1.934380e-04  16.7130833
13         PUM GRAZED GRASS 2.352360e-05   2.0324400
14         PUM GRAZED GRASS 9.307130e-05   8.0413621
15         PUM GRAZED GRASS 6.701040e-05   5.7896950
16         PUM GRAZED GRASS 1.635820e-04  14.1334936
17         PUM GRAZED TREES 9.899350e-05   8.5530351
18         PUM GRAZED TREES 1.838510e-04  15.8847159
19     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 2.514190e-04  21.7226206
20     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 4.024630e-04  34.7728153
21     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 2.872780e-05   2.4820856
22     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 1.362320e-04  11.7704208
23     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 3.141210e-05   2.7140027
24     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 4.019900e-04  34.7319472
25     HAF GRAZED NAT GRASS 1.172680e-04  10.1319880
26         HAF MATURE TREES 1.119040e-04   9.6684926
27         HAF MATURE TREES 5.910299e-03 510.6498559
28         HAF MATURE TREES 1.877630e-04  16.2227583
29         HAF MATURE TREES 1.108890e-04   9.5807732
30         HAF MATURE TREES 2.993970e-04  25.8678921
31         HAF MATURE TREES 2.734273e-03 236.2411852
32         HAF MATURE TREES 1.493940e-03 129.0764039
33            HAF YNG TREES 3.002123e-03 259.3833846
34            HAF YNG TREES 3.825811e-03 330.5500423
35            HAF YNG TREES 4.210470e-04  36.3784414
36            HAF YNG TREES 4.857110e-05   4.1965421
37            HAF YNG TREES 4.273473e-03 369.2280804
38            HAF YNG TREES 6.639711e-03 573.6710181
39            HAF YNG TREES 3.178988e-03 274.6645952
40 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 3.755320e-05   3.2446005
41 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 4.076420e-04  35.2202696
42 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 1.699937e-03 146.8745987
43 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 6.935580e-04  59.9234425
44 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 4.140920e-04  35.7775064
45 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 1.751798e-03 151.3553348
46 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 7.242830e-05   6.2578080
47 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 4.187560e-05   3.6180550
48 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  1 2.898640e-05   2.5044226
49       S.L NAT GRZD GRASS 9.190450e-05   7.9405490
50       S.L NAT GRZD GRASS 5.594110e-05   4.8333091
51     S.L  pheasant woods  1.262860e-05   1.0911135
52     S.L  pheasant woods  4.442918e-03 383.8681083
53     S.L  pheasant woods  1.283240e-04  11.0871588
54     S.L  pheasant woods  7.984330e-04  68.9846040
55     S.L  pheasant woods  8.069750e-05   6.9722628
56     S.L  pheasant woods  4.474640e-06   0.3866091
57     S.L  pheasant woods  2.641400e-04  22.8216663
58 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  2 1.141300e-04   9.8608365
59 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  2 1.161330e-04  10.0339052
60 S.L GRZD IMPRVD GRASS  2 2.696315e-03 232.9616580
61         S.L GRAZED TREES 9.302370e-05   8.0372445
62         S.L GRAZED TREES 2.917180e-05   2.5204423
63         S.L GRAZED TREES 9.377750e-05   8.1023777
64                S.F TREES 1.028086e-03  88.8266135
65               S.F ARABLE 1.720700e-05   1.4867253
66               S.F ARABLE 1.654900e-05   1.4298659
67               S.F ARABLE 2.200800e-05   1.9015200
68      S.F FLORISTIC GRASS 1.555882e-03 134.4281958
69      S.F FLORISTIC GRASS 2.232400e-05   1.9287530
70      S.F FLORISTIC GRASS 2.808200e-05   2.4263203
71         S.F GRAZED GRASS 1.489970e-04  12.8733386
72         S.F GRAZED GRASS 1.001910e-04   8.6564852
```

Comment: It would be much easier for others to experiment with your code if it was included directly in your question, rather than as a screenshot image. Thanks.

Comment: factor(your_variable) should clean it, or drop=T when splitting help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8485403) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: `?droplevels` ....

Comment: Hi thanks for this - drop levels dosn't seem to work...perhaps I am using it wrong? I just dont understand why it is retaining all these blank levels on the graph!?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks all - finally worked out what I needed to do, which was to use the argument 'drop= T' within the 'boxplot' command, changing the last line above from

```
boxplot(K.CM.DAY~site.id, data = HAFREN1)
```

to

```
boxplot(K.CM.DAY~site.id, data = HAFREN1, drop = T)
```